# Google ReCaptcha V3 tricked by fake gclids

Tags: spam-prevention, recaptcha-v3

I believe Google Recaptcha v3 might be able to be tricked by opening contact form pages with fake gclid's.

I have investigated some questionable form submissions on a clients website and can see that the recaptcha score is high however the form submission clearly is not a good submission. I notice that the page is called with a gclid parameter and believe that a fake gclid is aiding form submissions from bots to proceed.

I have checked the same period for number of clicks reported in google ads and none have been counted.

Is anyone else seeing this scenario?

Investigated Form submissions and validated against google ads reported clicks for the same period.